Illustrator CS6: how to change the default stroke thickness setting
How to change the default stroke thickness setting from the existing 0.353mm to any value?
So, when you select an object and select a stroke color, the stroke thickness will be 0.2mm instead of 0.353mm?

It's about assigning a default to every (different) thing already existing in the graphic without a border, so that when selecting it and choosing the option to assign a border, its default thickness is 0.2 mm, and not 0.353 mm (1pt) as it is by default. (I assume that it is written somewhere in the installation file, e.g. Ai Pref, where you can change it so that objects move up without inserting -, and down with the inserted - / sign, the opposite of what is the default in AI /)

The setting is dependent on what you had selected before you started the object. So if you select a line with 0.2mm before you do something it will be 0.2mm if you select something else it will be something else. If you have never selected anything it defaults to the default graphic style of the document, but again once you have selected anything it will continue with the setting of that object. If you want to change this permanently then you need to re save over the default template files but then again it will only affect the first thing you do in the document. (0.353mm == 1 pt)

It is not possible to directly set default stroke weights In Illustrator.
If you really want some specific measurement as a default. You can edit the Document Startup files, specifically the default Graphic Style.
Editing the Default Graphic Style in the startup files to contain a desired stroke weight will make all new documents started from that Document Profile default to whatever stroke weight has been set.

How to do it: If you really want some specific measurement as a default. You can edit the Document Startup files, specifically the default Graphic Style.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwtrr_36xNE
